Proof Peano curve is not derivable at any point.
First, define a function $f:[0,2]\to{[0,1]}，x\mapsto{0}(0\leq{x}\leq{\frac{1}{3}}\vee\frac{5}{3}\leq{x}\leq{2})，x\mapsto{3x-1}(\frac{1}{3}\leq{x}\leq\frac{2}{3})$，$x\mapsto{-3x+5}, x\mapsto1(\frac{2}{3}\leq{x}\leq{\frac{4}{3}})$
Then expand domain: $f(x+2)=f(x)$
Then define $x(t):=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(3^{2n-1}t)}{2^n}，y(t):=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(3^{2n-2}t)}{2^n}$
How to prove $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are not derivable?

What have you tried? You know the definition of the derivative. Try applying that definition at a point. I suggest trying it for $t = 0$ specifically to get a feel for the calculation. Then apply what you learn at a general point.

$f$ has two definitions between $\frac23$ and $\frac43$ and no definition between $\frac43$ and $\frac53$. Further, assuming that the second definition is supposed to be between $\frac 43$ and $\frac 53$ leaves a discontinuity at $\frac 53$, where it suddenly would drop from $1$ to $0$.
